# Add SQL Query And Variable to SharePoint ASPX Page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, sharepoint

I have created an aspx page on a sharepoint 2013 site. I have customized the pages css, buttons, and layout exactly as I need. Now my goal is to add a SQL connection to the database on our network to pull data based on currently logged in user. I have written the SQL query to basically be "Select "field" From DB Where SharePointUserloggedinname like 'db.table.field' . I have tested this query in sql management studio, and it works perfectly. My question, is how do I add this sql query portion into my aspx page, set the query result to a variable and then display the queries results(variable) to display via a text field/paragraph tag/or other.

I have added the namespaces, and c# portion provided below into my aspx page but I am unsure how & where to place the c# code to connect to the sql db, set the variable, and then call that variable to display in a field further down the page.

`

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System;"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic;"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.ComponentModel;"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data;"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing;"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq;"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text;"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading.Tasks;"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Windows.Forms;"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient;"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.Page" %>


<%@ public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private SqlDataReader reader = null;
public SqlDataReader Reader { get { return reader; } set { reader = value; } }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [totalHours] FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE] Where [DB].[dbo].[TABLE].[column] like 'persons name') = @variable1", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("variable1", "anonymous"));

        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
 %>
```

Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you've tested that query? Because it looks quite odd `[...]  like 'persons name') = @variable1`. There is no starting parenthesis for that, and the variable looks misplaced.

Comment: I have edited the sql query itself for display purposes on a public website, and prior to editing it did work properly via visual studio and sql mgmt studio. As far as the variable creation that piece was found via the article i mentioned, and was unsure of where to place this in the asp page.

Comment: I understand, but as it is written now it would throw an error. Perhaps you mean: `"SELECT [totalHours] FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE] Where [DB].[dbo].[TABLE].[column] like @variable1"`

Comment: Yes correct, my question though is where do I place this sql connection above in my aspx page, and how do I call this later on in a portion of my page

Answer (score 0):

You should not place your C# code into the page directly.

Instead you can make a user control following this guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231548.aspx

Then in your page you have to register a tag for the control

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="MyControls" 
    Namespace="KM.MyControls.MyControl" 
    Assembly="KM.MyControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=<Your token>" %>
```

and then you can use your control into the page:

```
<MyControls:MyUserControl runat="server"/>
```

source: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46629/how-to-put-custom-user-control-on-page-layout